# How to filter a pandas list of numerical values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
                     value_list  
0             [200000.00, 100.00, 25.00]                 
1                       [860000.00]                          
2                  [148000.00, 25.00]
```

I want a new column filtered_list which will filter out values less than 100 and greater 10000 so expected results

```
                     value_list                              filtered_list
0             [200000.00, 100.00, 25.00]                     [100.00]
1                       [860000.00]                          []
2                 [148000.00, 25.00, 9500]                   [9500]
```

How can I do this?

What I've tried:

```
df['filtered_list'] = df['value_list'].apply(lambda x: (e for e in x if e > 100 and e < 10000 ))
```

But this returned a generator object. Please advise.

Comment: would the use case let a regular python function do the job, or does it have to be a lambada function?

Comment: `(e for e in x ..)` (with parenthesis) will build a generator while `[e for e in x ...]` (brackets) will build a list

Comment: Note your input and output dataframes are not the same. Your test is wrong if you want to include 100 because you check values strictly greater than 100 (not equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [] to create a list instead of a generator ():

```
df['filtered_list'] = df['value_list'].apply(lambda x: [e for e in x if 100 <= e < 10000])
print(df)

# Output
                value_list filtered_list
0  [200000.0, 100.0, 25.0]       [100.0]
1               [860000.0]            []
2   [148000.0, 25.0, 9500]        [9500]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and use a double *listcomp*. So, assuming (`df`) is your dataframe, use :

```
df["filtered_list"] = [[n for n in l if 100 <= n <= 10000]
                          for l in df["value_list"]]
```

​Output:

```
print(df)

                value_list filtered_list
0  [200000.0, 100.0, 25.0]       [100.0]
1               [860000.0]            []
2   [148000.0, 25.0, 9500]        [9500]
```